# How can I find the Secure Attention Key (SAK) on my system and can I disable it?

Tags: security, linux-kernel, embedded, busybox

In answer to [My process was killed but I cannot understand the kernel notice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80857/2465), I was pointed to some [documentation on the Secure Attention Key (SAK) on Linux](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/SAK.txt). I have a embedded system generated using buildroot which uses `busybox` and the busybox init system. I am unable to find either `rc.local` or `rc.sysinit` on my system anywhere. I have looked online but I cannot find any documentation (other than the link above) that tells how I can identify what the SAK is for my system. Can anyone tell me how I can get this information and also if I can turn the SAK off? As my system is embedded and isolated from the internet I am not overly concerned with security breaches or hack attempts. The SAK seems to pop up out of nowhere and kills my main embedded application which is totally unacceptable so if I can turn this off it would be better for my needs (even if this means I have to reconfigure and build my kernel)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this mailing list post](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/681919?do=post_view_threaded) SAK is <kbd>«break»</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>. So you could be receiving it over the serial port. The kernel [sysrq documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt) agrees.

That kernel document also gives a solution: disable sysrq by `echo 0 >/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq`. Or, alternatively, only enable the ones you'd like.

You can also configure SAK using setserial, according to the [setserial man page](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_setserial.htm).

Busybox init probably runs the `/etc/init.d/rcS` shell script. It also runs other things out of `/etc/inittab`. I suggest looking at that shell script see where you should plop scripts to set these things.