# How to tell if console login is genuine?

Tags: linux, security, login

On Windows one can enforce pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to fire an interrupt that brings up the login window.

When logging onto a console of a Linux computer: How can I tell if this login is a real one or a mocked up on to steal my credentials?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming that you want to be protected against other normal users of the
system (if the adversary has root access, all bets are off), your
could in principle use a [secure attention
key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_attention_key):

> An operating system's Secure Attention Key is a security tool which is
>   provided as protection against trojan password capturing programs.  It
>   is an undefeatable way of killing all programs which could be
>   masquerading as login applications.  Users need to be taught to enter
>   this key sequence before they log in to the system.

([Linux 2.4.2 Secure Attention Key (SAK) handling, Andrew Morton, 18 March 2001](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/SAK.txt))

This related U&L question may be of interest: [How can I find the Secure Attention Key (SAK) on my system and can I disable it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80886/)

Comment: What could happen when SAK will be activated with an X server switched on?

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: I've tried that; it seems to be *roughly* equivalent to Ctrl+Alt+Backspace assuming you haven't disabled that.  I do remember that it seemed a bit buggier, though, but I can't recall any specifics.

Comment: I hit it frequently on my vtty, and after some time, the login didn't come back. That feels buggy, but +1 for an actually every-day-useful SysRq.

Comment: @Kevin: So if a user ran a legitimate X server (that necessarily is euid = 0, at least on PCs) on a tty≠7, its configuration has SAK disabled, then SAK isn’t that undefeatable as kernel docs claim? Suppose an emulated GUI DM runs on it.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: I think what it *actually* does is kill everything in your session and relaunch the "correct" thing, whatever that may be.  So if tty=7, you get a brand-new X, otherwise you get `login`, etc.  This is buggy because some fancy DEs like GNOME don't like being killed out of nowhere.  But if your attacker has euid=0, you've already lost anyway.

Comment: @Kevin: Note that the doc cited states that SAK is controlled from a keymap (`loadkeys`). Besides possibility of a compromised keymap, you should indeed know that X has *its own keyboard handler,* completely independent from the one of TUI consoles. That’s one of reasons for an X server to need root.

Comment: @Kevin: You also might misunderstand what euid = 0 means *exactly.* Every user may run a euid = 0 program (`sudo`, `su`, `X`, or even `ping`). What a regular user can’t is running an *arbitrary* program with euid = 0.

Comment: The docs say not to use SysRq because the kernel might not support it, but in my experience, Ubuntu at least does compile their kernels with it.

Comment: Modern X servers do not run as root (effective UID > 0).  On my machine `Xwayland` runs as `gdm`, and on top there is `Xorg` as `$USER`.  Does that have implications for SAK?

Comment: @Ned64: Nothing wrong that Wayland is currently used by a minority? OK, to be more precise, Ī̲ meant **the program that controls keyboard and display (in GUI mode) directly,** not necessarily a server of X11 protocol. It’s `Xorg` for me and `Xwayland` for you, but anyway, it must have euid = 0 and can cheat the keyboard, if configured to do so.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi Yes, that's right, but when an attacker has root access everything is lost anyway.  However, `Xwayland` sits on top and does not have `euid=0` if I understand the new concept correctly.  So, there could be keys that are filtered when `Xwayland` clients try to re-map them.

Comment: @Ned64: It doesn’t need to be *attacker*. A negligence (honest mistake) affecting the keyboard handler, not patched promptly, would be enough. My point is that while Linux permits userland software to listen the keyboard in VC_RAW/K_RAW, Secure Attention Key isn’t an undefeatable kernel-level imperative.

Comment: @Kevin If you _think_ you're at a login screen, then either A) GNOME isn't running B) The attacker's GNOME session is running and who cares C) The attacker has had unsupervised access to your logged-in session, which means you have a much bigger problem.

Comment: @Random832: Yeah, but GDM may be running, and it may do stupid things if it gets killed unexpectedly.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I'm not sure you can be over confident of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> login window on Windows, this is also the role of a virus/trojan to hijack interruption, and implementing it is very possible.

Second, if such mechanism is implemented both on Windows/Linux, it means that administrator privileges are surely compromised.

In Linux, if someone wrote a fake shell to display a prompt and catch your credentials, I guess basic <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> can be enough, if those signals are not caught to discover the trick. 
Also entering wrong credentials several time can help you to see any deviation from normal timer behaviour.

Switching between different console like also increase the probability to discover the trick.

But in any case you can not be sure 100% on any kind of system of trustworthiness  of your login prompt/window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>...<kbd>F7</kbd> to go into other tty, and log in from there.
You can also use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>. However, if someone is trying to steal your login and password using this method, it's still possible that you're being cheated on. Depends on what OS you're using, who had access to it and what kind of access did he have.

Generally, you can never be 100% sure, but if someone did this, I would assume he already has root access - so your login data would be meaningless to him.

Comment: If I were to set up such a trap, I would definitely have my program run on every tty. Keep in mind that those you access with the control keys aren't particularly safer.

Comment: Fair point; this was the best what came to my mind.

Comment: Can some magic sysrq help you?

Answer (score 0):

A user (even not root) having a physical access to the console can do such a con trick.

Log in through `ssh` and check which processes operate on a virtual console you want to log in locally. Whether is it `getty` (for a TUI tty) or other legitimate display manager? Has it UID = 0?

If any of two is false, then the *hostname* `login:` banner is certainly forged. But, as state answers already written, it doesn’t help against a wrongdoer having his/her privileges already escalated to `root`.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: you can't tell.

But if the login prompt command has been replaced, it means that the attacker has root access on the machine. In this case he/she could as well:

- have installed a keylogger to steal your password. You can mitigate the problem by using unique password, so the attacker won't be able to access other online services you use;
- login as you (or as any other user) on the machine, simply by changing the password, or access your (or anyone else's) files.

Therefore worrying whether the login prompt is legitimate or not is a moot point.

As a general rule, you should not login to a machine which you think might be compromised.

Comment: I could design a program which imitates the behaviour of a login prompt, and run it in every TTY without root privileges (as myself). If done correctly, it would be impossible to distinguish the real prompt from the program's output, inviting you to enter your credentials. However, note that it would take root privileges to authenticate you (making the trap completely transparent), so if the login fails and you're sure you didn't make a typo... you may assume you've been trapped (too late though).

Comment: How do you install the fake login without being root?

Comment: You don't install it. You simply use your own account to log into every terminal, and run the fake login there. Users who try to use a terminal after that will find your fake prompt, running as you, not the `login` program running as root. I'm not assuming that the actual `login` program has been compromised, indeed.

Comment: Ah, I see. Clever, but in this way you must leave *your* account open to everyone. And once someone discovers the trick, if anyhow he manages to find a way to exit the fake login, expect him to take revenge by doing a `rm -rf ~` :)

Comment: … or with `su` *username*, or access your (or anyone else's) files [directly with root privileges].

Comment: @dr01. Login as normal. When you're ready to start your `~/bin/fakelogin`, use `exec ~/bin/fakelogin` so that when it exits (for whatever reason) your user account is logged out and the real login prompt presented to the other user.

Comment: Normally when you try to steal a password in a prompt, you log it and write "Invalid login.", then exit your program.  So, no need to authenticate using `$euid=0`.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @dr01 just do `exec fakelogin`